# MS EXCEL 2013 - Matching value from a column and returning values from next column

Tags: microsoft-excel

In column A, I have weeks from 1 to 52. In column B I have "TRUE" and "FALSE". I want to check all the TRUE from Column B and want to return all the corresponding numbers from Column A.
Then values from column A will be sent to some other column which will further match those numbers and then count the total number.

Currently I am trying this formula:
 `=IF($B$2:$B$54=TRUE,COUNTIFS(tempDailyFeed_23July!$B$2:$B$1048576,"=abc",tempDailyFeed_23July!$BU$2:$BU$1048576,$A$2:$A$54),"")`

Here B2 to B54 is my column containing TRUE and FALSE, while A2 to A54 contains a number from 1 to 52. In the `COUNTIF` function I have given the required condition for matching from other table.

Comment: Are the values in column **B** `Text` or `Boolean` ??

Comment: It's not exactly clear, but I think you're saying you want to count the occurrences where tempDailyFeed_23July!$B$2:$B$1048576 equals "abc" and tempDailyFeed_23July!$BU$2:$BU$1048576 equals any of the week numbers in column A of the current sheet where column B is TRUE.  If that's right, @Gary's Student 's answer will set you well on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a table of **20** items.  In **C1** enter `TRUE`.  In **C2** enter the ***array formula***:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$20,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$20=$C$1,ROW($B$1:$B$20)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Adjust the formula to match the dimensions of your table.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're actually trying to do what I guessed in the comment above, then here is a way to do it.

I had a hard time using COUNTIFS() to do this because it's not possible to put logical operators in the criteria.

In any case, here is a solution with the caveat already mentioned:

[image]

The formula in C2 is the array formula that G's Student gave earlier.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$16,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$16=TRUE,ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS($A$2:$A2))),"")
```

Column D has some text names to mimic your range `tempDailyFeed_23July!$B$2:$B$1048576`, and column E has week numbers to mimic your range with the week numbers.  (It can't be `tempDailyFeed_23July!$B$2:$B$1048576`as you have in the IF() formula in your question). OR maybe I'm completely barking up the wrong tree here.

The formula in F2 is another array formula:

`=IFERROR(IF((MATCH(1,1*(E2=C$2:C$7),0))*(D2="abc")>0,1,""),"")`

It finds the rows where Name ="abc" AND Week Num is one of the Weeks in column C (the Weeks in column A where column B is TRUE).